# Why does parseJSON fail on the following response from server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In my firebug I see the server respond with:

```
{"status":"Results Found","errorcode":"0","result":[{"name":"test","id":"1"},{"name":"some","id":"2"}]}


When I do the following I get a "o is null" error.
$.ajax({
 type: "get",
 url: "http://someurl",
 data: $("#eventsearch").serialize(),
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(msg){
var o = $.parseJSON(msg); //o is NULL error
}
```

However when I do parseURL on the same string but not as a server response everything is good. What is going on here?

```
var t = '{"status":"Results Found","errorcode":"0","result":[{"name":"test","id":"1"},{"name":"some","id":"2"}]}';

var o = $.parseJSON(t); //everything is good here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you set the `dataType:json` the json is already parsed you don't have to do

`var o = $.parseJSON(msg);`

you can do

```
console.log(msg.result[0].name);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your specify  `dataType: 'json'` in call to jQuery's ajax function msg is already an object, created via parsing JSON data returned from server. jQuery takes your job in parsing response.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(msg.result[0].id); // gives u 1
console.log(msg.result[1].id); // gives u 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
var o = $.parseJSON(msg); //o is NULL error
```

is not syntactically able to produce that error. Even if `parseJSON` were to return null, assigning that null value to a new variable (which you then promptly ignore) is not an error.

Are you not showing all of the relevant code?

Is the problem perhaps that you try to use `o` before the ajax operation has completed -- that is, without waiting until the success callback is called?